# Bootstrap 3 not scrolling properly in iphone?

Tags: iphone, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am facing a problem in mobile view (iPhone) of my website: http://www.html5css3tuts.com/turkey

When I open this in iPhone, scrolling the website is very hard. It gets sticky when we scroll up. It's working very well in other mobiles even in the iPad also. I am not able to find where it's getting problem.

Answer (score -2):

Use  tag in the page for mobile resolution:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: which tag you are saying ?

Comment: can u please say it to me i have no idea.

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: this i have written <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Content</title>

Comment: best example refer it  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html

Comment: okk thanks but still the problem is same as the viewport is setted to <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> as they have mentioned

Comment: try different methods